# "Shrinking" open sets technique.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So I was reading a lot of proofs in geometry and analysis and sometimes the follow phrase gets used "if necessary, shrink open sets $U$ and $V$ so that property $X$ is satisfied" or something along the lines of that. What exactly does this mean?

Here is an example. I was reading something in differential geometry and this is one of those "is this chart dependant" questions. I think this is differential geometry's way of asking "is this thing well-defined". Anyways, when defining the Tangent Space, one will be asked "what if we use another chart?".

> So let $X$ be a manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with chart $\phi: U \subset \mathbb{R}^k \to X$ and $\phi(0) = x \in X$.  Now suppose we have another chart $\psi: V \to  X$ with $\psi(0) = x$, **then by shrinking $U$ and $V$, we may assume $\phi(U) = \psi(V)$**. I believe this is so that we can define the map $h = \psi^{-1}\circ \phi$, because if the image sets are not equal, then $\psi^{-1}$ may not be defined on $\phi(U)$.

Or is "shrink" here imply that the image sets are "equal up to diffeomorphism"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "taking a subset in the obvious way". The sets $\phi(U), \psi(V)$ are open neighborhoods of $x$, and thus so is $\phi(U) \cap \psi(V)$; by setting $U' = \phi^{-1}(\phi(U) \cap \psi(V))$ and $V' = \psi^{-1}(\phi(U) \cap \psi(V))$, and letting $\phi' = \phi_{U'}$ and $\psi' = \psi_{V'}$, we have new $U', V', \phi', \psi'$ such that $\phi'(U') = \psi'(V')$, and these agree with $\phi,\psi$ on the set we are considering.

Comment: I didn't think about setting the domain to the preimage

Answer (score 2):

I think it means that there exists open sets containing $0$: $U_1 \subset U$ and $V_1\subset V$ such that $\phi(U_1) = \psi(V_1)$. One can then use the charts $\phi|_{U_1}$ and $\phi|_{V_1}$ instead of $U$ and $V$.

The advantage of "by shrinking, we can assume" is that one avoids defining new objects and new notations explicitly.

Comment: Well I thought of that too, but $\phi$ and $\psi$ can map to completely different things, but looks like Mees took care of that problem.